# Deriving Lagrangian for common a class of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I am interested in constructing a Lagrangian for a PDE of type

$$
u_t(t,x) - F(u,u_t,u_x)=0
$$

such that for some functional $\quad I[u] = \int D[u]\mathcal{L}[u,u_t,u_x]$
its associated Euler Lagrange Equations satisfy the above PDE

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u}
-
\partial_t\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_t}
-
\partial_x\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}
=
u_t(t,x) - F(u,u_t,u_x)=0.
$$

Really I am trying to understand which class of PDE's are the kind that are the Euler Lagrange Equations associtated with some extremal functional $I[u]$.

Is there a way to work backwards from the PDE to $\mathcal{L}[u,u_t,u_x]$? For example, if $F(u,u_t,u_x) = u_x$, how would you do it, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

In general, not every differential equation is coming from a Lagrangian, see [Douglas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics) on that matter.

So even if we assume
$$
F(u,u_t,u_x)=F(u,u_t)
$$
you might not be able to find a suitable Lagrangian for your problem. On that note, note that
$$
\tilde{F}(u,u_t,u_x)=\partial_t u(x,t)-F(u,u_t,u_x)
$$
is again a function of the same form as $F$ and therefore you are essentially asking if every first-order PDE in $(x,t)$
$$
\tilde{F}(u,u_t,u_x)=0
$$
is coming from a Lagrangian. And the answer is no. Giving some conditions or having a more explicit form (or even estimates, for that matter) of $F$ might help.